# Map values in columns DF given dictionary input

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I have a dataframe with values, and I expect a dictionary with replacement indications as follow.
{cellsvalue1: replacementevalue2}

If the first column matches with the key, the second column gets the value of that key.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                   "result": [100, 200, 300]})

new_values =  {1: 1000,
       3: 3000}
```

The expected result is

| id | result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 200 |
| 3 | 3000 |

Any proposal would help me,

Thanks

Comment: `df["result"] = df["id"].map(new_values).fillna(df["result"])` ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Timeless has already pointed out, the `map()` method does what you want, so the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3],
                   "result": [100, 200, 300]})
new_values =  {1: 1000, 3: 3000}
df["result"] = df["id"].map(new_values).fillna(df["result"])
print(df)
```

produces the output:

```
   id  result
0   1  1000.0
1   2   200.0
2   3  3000.0
```